# Get username windows in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, authentication

i need to get the username of windows of my user in my intranet site using javascript / react, i try with several modules, such as os, userinfo and i cant get the username,
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add an input so the user will type it. If the browsers were to allow retrieving the user names by third party libraries, it would be a mess in the web world

Comment: I understand that there is a way in which the user types, I would just like to know if there is a way for the code itself to access this information.

Comment: There is no way, other than having the users install a plugin or extension.